# Entering community wiki in grace period removes reputation

Tags: bug, community-wiki, grace-period

The [FAQ entry](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/11741/200500) on CW reads:

> The original author keeps the reputation gained (or lost) before their
>   post entered community mode.

However, [I just discovered](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15710298/revisions) that converting a post to CW within the 5 minute grace period removes any reputation already gained from upvotes. This is, at the very least, undocumented behavior.

IMO, converting to CW within the grace period should count as separate entry in the post's revision history, in much the same way as edits by other users do. Additionally, regarding reputation:

- Either the FAQ should be updated to reflect that CW during the grace period is an exception to the above mentioned rule, or
- The behavior should be altered, so that reputation from upvotes prior to CW are retained regardless of whether the change occurs during or after the grace period

I believe the second option is much more intuitive and would cause less confusion in the future.

Comment: Do you want to keep the downvotes as well? :-) What if the reason for changing the post to CW was that I just forgot to click that before posting? I don't think there is a need to change the way it works.

Answer (score 4):

Everything done during the grace period of the first edit is handled as it was done in the first edit; if you make a question a CW during the grace period of the first edit, it is like the question was a CW since the beginning.

The FAQ question has been written before the grace period feature was added. Maybe a note could be added, just to make sure somebody else doesn't get confused by that. To me, what you are describing is the expected behavior.